# How can I set a standard Sound Output for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound, settings

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS resets my Sound Output to "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Audio" at every restart.

Is there a way to set a standard Sound Output for Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Desktop:

- Run Settings
- Go to Sound→Output→Output Device
- Select appropriate device from drop down list

[image: Screenshot]

If you don't see your device in the list you may set it by modifying `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file.